# Cordova app doesn't start up in the emulator

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I am trying to make an Android app using Cordova but when I try it to run it in the emulator the app never loads even though Android runs correctly. Here is what I've done:

```
cordova create app-dir com.example.app App
cd app-dir
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
cordova run android
```

this starts up the emulator but the app is never loaded; however when I open the Android project using Android Studio and run the app from there in the emulator the app starts up properly.

For the Virtual Android Device I am using Android 7.1.1 and API 25. My cordova version is 8.0.0. I am also running this on Ubuntu.

I'd like to know why `cordova run android` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `cordova` utility to deploy the application to the emulator from the command line:

```
$ cordova emulate android
```

**Deploy to Device:** 
To push an app directly to the device, make sure USB debugging is enabled on your device, and use a mini USB cable to plug it into your system.

You can push the app to the device from the command line:

```
 $ cordova run android
```

Alternately within Eclipse, right-click the project and choose **Run As → Android Application.**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use it?You can use android studio to run the app and packed it

Comment: Let's say I don't like having things that do not work.

Comment: This is not an answer. Consider asking such counter questions via comments on the original question